# How to edit bst file to reorder editors and book title in @incollection?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib, harvard-style

How to edit the bst file to order editors before the book title in @incollection? The current code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{key,
Author = {Tony Soprano},
Booktitle = {Book title},
Editor = {Sonny Crockett and Ricardo Tubbs },
Pages = {1-10},
Publisher = {Oxford: OUP},
Title = {Title of the chapter},
Year = {2001}}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\noindent \cite{key} wrote it first. 

\bibliographystyle{degruyterbib}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

gives the following (undesired) order:
[image]

while the desired result is the sequence with "in: editors (eds.)," before the book title, as in:
[image]

I've already reordered other elements except this problematic one in the .bst file (based on Alexis Dimitriadis linquiry.bst). Here is the relevant functions:

```
 FUNCTION {bbl.in}
 { "in:" }     

 FUNCTION {word.in}
 { bbl.in capitalize
   " " * }

 FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
 { "(ed.)," }

 FUNCTION {format.editors}
 { editor empty$
     { "" }
     { editor format.names
       editor num.names$ #1 >
         { ", " * bbl.editors * }
         { ", " * bbl.editor * }
       if$
       }
     if$
     }

FUNCTION {format.in.editors}
 { editor empty$
     { "" }
     { editor format.names.ed
     }
   if$
   }
```

including the major one I'm having a problem with:

```
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
 { booktitle empty$
 { "" }
 { editor empty$
     { word.in booktitle "t" change.case$ emphasize * }
     { word.in booktitle "t" change.case$ emphasize *
       ", " *
       editor num.names$ #1 >
         { bbl.editors }
         { bbl.editor }
       if$
       * " " *
       format.in.editors *
       }
     if$
     }
   if$
   }
```

Comment: Is the file `degruyterbib.bst` available online somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: @Mico Yes, it's here: https://github.com/boliver1981/latex

Comment: I've taken a look at the innards of `degruyterbib.bst`. I must say it's quite messy: It appears to have been first created about 20 years ago, and it has been hacked repeatedly since then. Rather than try to hack the style file even more (and probably introduce conflicts with previous hacks!), I would like to recommend that you familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility which is part of the [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. The `makebst` utility is menu-driven and easy to follow, and its output is a bespoke bibliography style file.